# display events from fullcalendar into a HTML list

Tags: javascript

I have `fullcalendar.io` widget, that works fine but I have some problem to get all events into html list.

First of all I have:

```
const EventsOfTheDay = app.store.find('events', {
      allDay: true,
      sort: 'event_start'
    })
      .then(results => {
        this.events = results;
        console.log(results);
      });
```

that result in:

[image: console log result]

I have problem to fetch only name, date and description of all events and display all in html list, can someone help me with that?

Comment: You need to loop through them with each and build your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list like this:

```
<ul id="list">    
</ul>
```

Iterate each event and create a list item (node) and appended it to the list above.

```
const EventsOfTheDay = app.store.find('events', {
    allDay: true,
    sort: 'event_start'
  })
  .then(results => {
    results.forEach((entry) => {
      var ul = document.getElementById('list');
      var node = document.createElement('li');
      var nodeText = document.createTextNode(entry.name + ',' + entry.date + ',' + entry.description);
      ul.appendChild(node);
    });
  });
```

Comment: i get Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: Check my edit, it should be `results.forEach` instead of `this.events.forEach`.

Comment: no errors but i get this https://i.ibb.co/tctWtR3/aassff.png apparently 3 values but empty

Comment: Add a `console.log(entry)`  before `var ul = document.getElementById('list');` and share the result. But you can try `results[entry].name + ',' + results[entry].date + ',' + results[entry].description`

Comment: with your second method i get Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: Forget my last suggestion, my original answer is right but the problem is that the fields you want to use are functions and not values. Expand one of those and add a print screen to see if I can help.

Comment: Try replacing `entry.name` with `data.attributes.name`.

Comment: Sorry, it's `event.data.attributes.name`

Comment: EventsWidget.js:30 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined

Comment: It's `entry.data.attributes.name`. I need a coffee...

Comment: thanks, i've found a solution, added a class and then i can access the attributes wth:


          {this.events.map((event) => (
            <li>{event.name()} - {event.description()}</li>, your help is precious by the way